# how pass parameter to php class by class()::function()

Tags: php, class

How pass parameter to PHP class by `class()::function()`?

```
class greenHouse{
    public function __construct(connection $con){
    }

    public function show(){
    }

}

$nameclass = 'greenHouse';
$namefunction = 'show';
$nameclass::$namefunction();
```

works

```
$nameclass = 'greenHouse';
$namefunction = 'show';
$nameclass($con)::$namefunction();
```

doesn't work

I want to pass a parameter to the class with `$nameclass($con)::$namefunction();`. How do I do that in PHP?

Comment: A class is the blue print , object is what you interact with.
$obj = new  greenHouse($cnx); or            $obj = new  $className($cnx);

Comment: Why do you want to create class based on the string and call the function by string as well? Why don't you use `$greenHouse = new greenHouse();` and then `$greenHouse->show();`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to call a function statically with that notation...

```
$nameclass = 'greenHouse';
$namefunction = 'show';
$class = new $nameclass($con);
$class->$namefunction();
```

Comment: i whant daynamic class

Comment: Did you read or try my code? Did it not do what you are expecting?

Comment: Perfect, Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

You can instantiate an object and immediately discard it by calling `new` within braces:

```
class Test
{
    private $name;

    function __construct($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    function speak()
    {

        echo $this->name;
    }

    function __destruct()
    {
        echo 'dead';
    }
}
$class='Test';
$method='speak';


(new $class('David'))->$method();

echo ' is ';

$temp = new $class('John');
$temp->$method();

echo ' is ';

//Daviddead is John is dead
```

So in your case:

```
(new $nameclass($con))->$namefunction();
```

Comment: Missing a ) there